# Plot points on a line in chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I am using chart.js to plot simple line charts. I want to show the points red in my line. For example i have passed an array as a dataset of numbers from 1 to 100. I want to show red that points which are even. Is this possible in chart.js.

I understand that i can go through that array and take out the even values from that array and then pass that array to the dataset. Can you plz help in this regard. here is my dataset code

here is my dataset

```
datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Assay Values',
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: data.assay_value,
            spanGaps: false
        },
```

data.assay_values is the array containing an array.

any kind of help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `data.assay_values` contains an array of numbers (for example `[65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]`), and that you only want the chart to show the even values, you can use the below code to process your data array into a new array, only keeping the even numbers.

Keep in mind that you also have to build a new `labels` array because your dataset data array must be the same length as your chart labels (because each index in the data maps to the corresponding labels index).

Please note, since you didn't provide any detail about your `labels` array in your question, this code assumes you have an array called `labels` that contains an array of strings.  You will need to change this according how you defined your labels in your implementation.

```
var evenData = [];
var newLabels = [];

data.assay_values.forEach(function(e, i) {
  // only take the even values
  if (e % 2 === 0) {
    evenData.push(e);
    newLabels.push(labels[i]);
  }
});
```

Then change your chart.js chart config to use your new labels and data arrays like this.

```
var data = {
  labels: newLabels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Assay Values',
    fill: false,
    lineTension: 0,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
    borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
    borderDash: [],
    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
    pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
    pointBorderWidth: 1,
    pointHoverRadius: 5,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
    pointRadius: 1,
    pointHitRadius: 10,
    data: evenData,
    spanGaps: false
  }]
};

// configure your chart options here
var options = {};

// ctx is a jQuery instance or 2d context of the canvas of where we want to draw the chart.
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line', 
  data: data, 
  options: options 
});
```

Comment: i tried this but this did not work, also there is difference between what i ask and what we are doing here. Actually i don't want to push the elements in array because i have already an array i just want to specify some points in that array . For example i already plot a line between 1 to 100 and there is data-set available. i just want to specify some points in the chart

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will update my answer accordingly with a solution to what you are looking for.

Comment: i got solution brother need not to worry :)